# JTable Cell Data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am facing a problem  with JTable cell data  in Java (Swing based application),

In each cell of JTable if  I entered any data it is automatically appending to old data,
instead  of that I want new data every time in that cell is just like Excel sheet Cell
(For  example in Excel sheet  when ever we want enter some data in a cell, at that moment old data of the cell  is eraised and it allow new data ) my problem is simillar to  that only

Advanced Thanks

Comment: maybe you are right, please edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: have a look at http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/26/table-editing/ - it might do what you want. If that doesn't help, it's back to @mKorbel's suggestion :-)

Answer (score 1):

From kleopatra's link, there is another link: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/20/table-select-all-editor/

The code in there will **select** the content of the cell, you can modify the code to **delete** the contents instead of select.